# Exporting a Process from jBPM

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management

I'm very new to jBPM, running the most recent build with the BusinessCentral portal.I want to export a project so that I can add it to an external repository. Is there a way to export a project as a whole by downloading all files, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with git.

**For exporting:**

You can essentially create a git repo on your computer, attach the business central as a remote host and pull in the changes.
You can see the ssh of your project if you click on your project and go into "Settings".

so:

1. Create a directory on your computer
2. `git init`
3. Execute `git remote add origin ssh://wbadmin@localhost:8001/MySpace/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME`
   notice the username in this url, in my case 'wbadmin'
4. `git pull origin master`
5. when prompted enter wbadmin as password

See also tutorial 3.7.2 https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.36.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_business_application_with_business_assets
This tutorial lets you import and then export again.

**For Importing**

See: https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.36.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_run_your_business_application
Import your business assets project into Business Central

Comment: killing my head on getting the same wbadmin did the trick i created a new account but it was not working ... thanks for explicitly putting it on really helped. For all use ssh with wbadmin/wbadmin or any account with similar roles phew what a heck.